# C0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION Exception with Progress Openedge when calling a Web Service

Tags: soap, access-violation, openedge, progress-4gl

I am trying to hit an external web service using Progress OE 11.5. When I execute the code from GUI Procedure Editor or the CHUI Procedure Editor, it crashes when calling the API

```
RUN ProcessTrack IN hTrackPortType(INPUT lcRequest, OUTPUT lcResponse) no-error.
```

I don't get any errors. The progress GUI window just crashes.

When I traced the logs it has "C0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION" exception. Any idea why this is caused? But when I access the same web services from SoapUI or from a Python program it works fine. I am not sure if Progress OpenEdge has any access restrictions to contact the apis.

I have the full stack trace here.

```
=====================================================
PROGRESS stack trace as of Fri Aug 07 12:26:40 2020
=====================================================

Progress OpenEdge Release 11.5 build 1114 on WINNT 

Startup parameters:
-pf C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\startup.pf,-cpinternal ISO8859-1,-cpstream ISO8859-1,-cpcoll Basic,-cpcase Basic,-d mdy,-numsep 44,-numdec 46,(end .pf),-param C:\.....\api_request.p

Exception code: C0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION
Fault address:  025C21CC 1C3:0034002D 

Registers:
EAX:086496B8
EBX:00000002
ECX:03100000
EDX:03100000
ESI:59DF2175
EDI:085AA1E0
CS:EIP:0023:025C21CC
SS:ESP:002B:00F4BFA0  EBP:00F4BFD0
DS:002B  ES:002B  FS:0053  GS:002B
Flags:00210206


Debugging dll: C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\bin\DBGHELP.DLL
Symbol Path:
 C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\bin;C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\pdbfiles


Call Stack:
Address   Frame
025C21CC  00F4BF9C  0000:00000000 
085AA1E0  00F4BFD0  0000:00000000 
59DF27DB  00F4BFDC  WSDLAttribute::getHandle+3F52B
59DA415C  00F4F130  WSDLArray_Empty+23ABC
59DCD9A0  00F4F144  WSDLAttribute::getHandle+1A6F0
59E502A8  00F4F198  WSDLAttribute::getHandle+9CFF8
59E5032C  00F4F1CC  WSDLAttribute::getHandle+9D07C
59DCF04E  00F4F204  WSDLAttribute::getHandle+1BD9E
59D9B724  00F4F240  WSDLArray_Empty+1B084
59E50403  00F4F260  WSDLAttribute::getHandle+9D153
59D55D6F  00F4F2A0  csp_tweakFileURL+312F


** ABL Stack Trace **

--> C:\....\p56215_api_request.ped at line 54  (C:\.....\p56215_api_request.ped)
    adecomm/_runcode.p at line 665  (adecomm/_runcode.r)
    ExecuteRun adeedit/_proedit.p at line 3613  (adeedit/_proedit.r)
    RunFile adeedit/_proedit.p at line 10625  (adeedit/_proedit.r)
    USER-INTERFACE-TRIGGER adeedit/_proedit.p at line 1985  (adeedit/_proedit.r)
    adeedit/_proedit.p at line 12280  (adeedit/_proedit.r)
    _edit.p at line 408  (C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\_edit.r)

** Persistent procedures/Classes **

** PROPATH **
.,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\ablunit.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\adecomm.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\adecomp.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\adedesk.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\adedict.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\adeedit.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\adeicon.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\aderes.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\adeshar.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\adeuib.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\adeweb.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\adexml.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\dataadmin.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\OpenEdge.BusinessLogic.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\OpenEdge.Core.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\OpenEdge.ServerAdmin.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\prodict.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\protools.pl,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\bin

** Databases (logical/type/physical) **

** End of Protrace **
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [KnowledgeBase post](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/ACCESS-VIOLATION-calling-a-service-on-Soap) indicates that this is a known error. If you run a version below 11.7.1 you should consider upgrading to the latest version of 11.7 (currently 11.7.6). If you run a version later than 11.7.1 that's mentioned in the article you should  consider contacting Progress support.

EDIT: since running 11.5 upgrading should be a priority!

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I am only using 11.5.

Comment: Here's another related K-Base artikel mentioning a possible workaround: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Knowledge/ACCESS-VIOLATION-calling-a-SOAP-service-from-PAS-instance

Comment: @davidbilla Check the link from Mike but consider upgrading to 11.7!

Comment: Thank you for the response Mike and Jensd. I tried the workaround in Mike's link, but it did not work. I guess I have to try it on a 11.7 installation.